Azure AD SSO with Microsoft Graph API for Calendar Events causing infinite redirect loop in ASP.NET Core
I have an ASP.NET Core application where I've successfully implemented Azure AD Single Sign-On (SSO) with JWT Authentication. Now, I’m integrating the Microsoft Graph API to create calendar events using Calendars.ReadWrite permissions.
In the ConfigureServices method, I’ve added the following code:
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
.EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "Calendars.ReadWrite" })
.AddInMemoryTokenCaches()
.AddMicrosoftGraph();

On the Events/Index page, I’m attempting to acquire an access token as shown below:
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()

{
string[] scopes = { "Calendars.ReadWrite" };
try
{
    var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes: scopes, authenticationScheme: OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    _logger.LogInformation($"Access Token Value {accessToken}");

    return View();
}
catch (MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException ex)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException {ex.Message}");
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Initiative");

    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Exception {ex.Message}");
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

}
When I visit the Events/Index page, I’m redirected to the login page, but then the app enters an infinite redirect loop and keeps spinning.
I would appreciate any insights on why this loop is happening and how to resolve it. Thanks in advance!

Does it request for the Calendars.ReadWrite permission when you log in? It looks like if that fails, you then require the user to log in, without specifying scopes for that request. So if the user then again logs in without that permission.. it'll end up with the same error again. Are you seeing that "MicrosoftIdentityWebChallengeUserException" in the logs?

We need the exception logs as Junnas said, I suggest you could also use browser's F12 network tab to see what happened from your application and the MSFT login page.

Here logs
Cache Refresh Reason: NotApplicable
ErrorCode: user_null
HTTP StatusCode 0
CorrelationId
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
10/03/2024 06:19:57 +00:00 [MsIdWeb] An error occured during token acquisition: "No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call. "
MSAL.NetCore.4.54.1.0.MsalUiRequiredException:
ErrorCode: user_null

@BrandoZhang
I have added log info. Could you please check. Thanks
